# Problem with the path and passing props to it (component with map)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a rather complicated problem, I know I probably did it completely incorrectly, but I have no idea how to do it using this.props.match.params and route path = "/:car-category.

```
<Route exact path={"/car-VAN/"} component={() => <CarCategory category={"VAN"} link={"/car-VAN/"}/>}/>
<Route exact path={"/car-SUV/"} component={() => <CarCategory category={"SUV"} link={"/car-SUV/"}/>}/>
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../sass/main.scss';
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
import {
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom';


const car1 = {
    carName: 'car-name-1',
    cat: 'VAN',
    vin: '31321414124214',
};

const car2 = {
    carName: 'car-name-1',
    cat: 'SUV',
    vin: '31321414124321',
};

const carAll = [car1, car2, car3];

class CarCategory extends Component{

    render() {

        const {category, link} = this.props;
        let sortCar = carAll.filter( el => el.cat === category );

        return(
            <>     <section className='cars-section'>
                <div className='container'>
                    <Helmet>
                        <title>{category}</title>
                    </Helmet>
                    <h1 className='head-text-category-mobile'>{category}</h1>
                    <div className='cars-gallery-container'>
                        {
                            sortCar.map(el => {
                                {
                                    return(<React.Fragment key={el.vin}>
                                            <div className='one-car-container'>
                                                <Link to={link + el.carName}>
                                                    <div className='car-div'>
                                                        <div className='car-name'>{el.carName}</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </React.Fragment>
                                    )
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default CarCategory
```

my english is not good and I can't explain it better, I hope someone can understand and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it dynamic using a param by setting your route to:

```
<Route exact path={"/car-:category"} component={CarCategory} />
```

CarCategory:

```
class CarCategory extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const { category } = this.props.match.params;
    const link = `/car-${category}/`;

    let sortCar = carAll.filter(el => el.cat === category);

    return (
        ...
        ...
    );
);
```

This will work but I would avoid using a route like `/car-:category`. Instead break it up like `/car/:category`.